# Updating fields of model using forms and views on Django 1.7

Tags: python, mysql, django, forms, e-commerce

In models.py my Product model is

```
class Product(models.Model):
    productName = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='1',blank=False,null=False, primary_key = True)
    userPhone = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='1')
    userid = models.ForeignKey(Account, default='1',null=True)
    productDesc = models.TextField(blank=False,null=False, default='1')
    productCategory = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=False, default='1')
    productPrice = models.DecimalField(default='0',blank=False,null=False, max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images', blank=True, null=True, default='1')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.productName
```

The form that I have to add new Products is,

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    productName = forms.CharField(label='Product Name')
    productCategory = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Category', queryset=Category.objects.all())
    productDesc = forms.CharField(label='Product Description', widget=forms.Textarea)
    productPrice = forms.DecimalField(label='Expected Price')
    userPhone = forms.CharField(label='Phone Number')
    picture = forms.ImageField(label='Upload Picture')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('productName', 'productCategory', 'productDesc', 'productPrice', 'userPhone', 'picture',) 

    def clean_productName(self):
        productName = self.cleaned_data['productName']
        try:
            Product.objects.get(productName=productName)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            return productName
        raise forms.ValidationError("A product under that name already exits. Rename your product.")

    def clean_productCategory(self):
        productCategory = self.cleaned_data['productCategory']

    def clean_productDesc(self):
        productDesc = self.cleaned_data['productDesc']

    def clean_productPrice(self):
        productPrice = self.cleaned_data['productPrice']

    def clean_userPhone(self):
        userPhone = self.cleaned_data['userPhone']

    def clean_picture(self):
        picture = self.cleaned_data['picture']
```

And to take form input, I have in my views.py file

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')   
def newProduct(request):
    if(request.method =='POST'):
        product_form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if product_form.is_valid():
            product = product_form.save(commit=True)
            product.save()
        else:
            print product_form.errors

    else:
        product_form = ProductForm()
    return render(request, 'market/postad.html', {'product_form':product_form} )
```

I want to update the userid field of Product model to the user_id of the logged in user. How do I go about doing that?

```
request.user.id
```

might give me the id of the logged in user. But how do I associate that with the product that is being entered into the database? (I am using MySQL database)

My AUTH_USER_MODEL isn't configured to Account. Is there any way to do it without configuring it?

My Account model is

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

I imported User from django.contrib.auth.models

Comment: Is your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` configured to `Account` ?

Comment: No. It isn't. I have just defined a model named Account with one field user.  user = models.OneToOneField(User)                                                   Makemigrations will not support it if I add AUTH_USER_MODEL = market.Account now.

Comment: So you would just get the `Account` object from `request.user` and associate that to `product.userid`  before you save

Comment: post your account model

Comment: I tried it. I get the following error now.                                              ValueError at /accounts/postad/

Cannot assign None: "Product.productCategory" does not allow null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In views.py (if your AUTH_USER_MODEL configured to Account)

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/', template_name='market/postad.html')   
def newProduct(request):
    product_form = ProductForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if(request.method =='POST'):
        if product_form.is_valid():
            product = product_form.save(commit=False)
            product.userid = Account.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
            product.save()
        else:
            print product_form.errors
    return render(request, template_name, {'product_form':product_form} )
```